# how to get camera trajectory and 3d point cloud data with rgbdslam

Tags: slam, navigation, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!Now i want to use the package "rgbdslam" to get the camera trajectory and the 3d point cloud data,but i do not know where the relative code is in the package "rgbdslam/src" . Furthemore,if i would like to save the camera trajectory and display the camera trajectory on the screen,so how should i do?
Thank you very much for your advice!
note:Ubuntu 11.10,ROS electric

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34628/how-to-get-camera-trajectory-and-3d-point-cloud-data-with-rgbdslam/) by [Ocean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2058/ocean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-05-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ocean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2058/ocean/) on 2012-05-23**:
In addition,i have download the groundtruth.txt and i want to get the estimated camera trajectory;so how shoule i do next? Or which code is used to input 'groundtruth.txt' and output its estimated trajectory?Hope that i have described the question clearly!Thank you very much!

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-07-09**:
groundtruth.txt is not used as input, just for comparison with the estimate file in the benchmark. If you want to use the trajectory in a ROS application, you should rather use the published tf information, e.g., as it is done for the octomap_server.

**Comment by [izik6666](https://answers.ros.org/users/21370/izik6666/) on 2015-01-14**:
HI Ocean, Have you figured out how to get camera trajectory? thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the GUI there is a menu option: "Processing"->"Save Trajectory Estimate". You can also use the ROS Service call interface, see the readme file.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) on 2012-07-02**:
Felix, You are telling the solution of saving Trajectory but I think Ocean wants to see trajectory so please tell how can we use data from trajectory_estimate.txt file

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-07-09**:
Depends on what you want to do. It's an easily parsable ascii file. I am not aware of any tools that use it as input (except for the rgbd benchmark)

**Comment by [WendyHu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4941/wendyhu/) on 2014-03-24**:
I used ROS service to save trajectory estimation. But this estimation is not for every image frame, just part of frame. I read the related code, found rgbdslam didn't add all of frame into the graph. But my result lost many frames and just less frames added into the graph (totally 800 frames, just 200 frames in the graph, so I just can get the camera pose estimation associated with these 200 frames). I want to make sure if this is normal. Does rgbdslam supply any another way to get camera estimation for every frame in sequence? Thanks in advance.